# CameraX image output resolution seems to be low when compared to device camera's image

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-camerax

I'm working on a custom camera module in android which uses cameraX library. I have observed that the resolution of image captured via cameraX seems to be odd from device camera app.

For example, I am using Moto G10 power to test this feature. **If I use the default device camera to take a picture, I get a resolution of 3000 * 4000 (in portrait)**. But I'm not able to get the same resolution when using the custom module built using the cameraX library. **It seems to be off, i,e 2250 * 4000 (in portrait)**.

I would like to get the same resolution image as device camera in cameraX module too. Not sure what configuration changes are needed to acheive this.

Below is the code used to setup imageCapture usecase.

```
            ImageCapture imageCapture = builder
                .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MAXIMIZE_QUALITY)
                .builder.setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio)//either 0 (4:3) or 1 (16:9) based on device orientation
                .setTargetRotation(previewView.getDisplay().getRotation())
                .setFlashMode(getFlashMode())
                .build();
```

I have Tried setting setTargetResolution `builder.setTargetResolution(new Size(3000, 4000))` instead of `.builder.setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio)`. It didnt help and resulted in image with resolution 960 * 720.

Any suggestions/guidance would be great, thanks!

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem, did you manage to obtain the image outputs equal to the device's camera?

Comment: Hey @Erick, seems it is an existing issue which is being tracked alreaday. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162121234?pli=1. Till date, with the latest version of cameraX - its not possible to get high resolution images.